# Directory Listing Denied On Mvc 4

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

My site developed with Asp.net MVC 4, when i enter site name **"Directory Listing Error"** is shown and when enter www.MySite.com/home an empty page is shown, please regard me.
How to fix this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Is this while running it from Visual Studio? Because this error is generally seen on IIS, and IIS 6 to boot.

Comment: No, it shown after upload to remote host.

Comment: My admin configured wildcard mapping for my domain but it is still displaying same page!

Answer (score 0):

If this works locally, and you're getting these results after publishing the site, the only conceivable thing that I could see occurring is the host doesn't have ASP.NET MVC 4 installed and running on their server.

One other possibility is that it's not registered properly. It's almost behaving like ASP.NET isn't registered with IIS. have your admin run aspnet_regiis.

Comment: I sure host have ASP.NET MVC 4 installed, but not work for me.